# XSL Convert XML file into 3 tables

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file about weather data of 3 different cities, now I want to use XSl convert it into 3 tables according to the location(Calgary,Charlottetown and Ottawa) attributes in my xml. The xls  I have now is just converting the xml into one table, Can anybody give me a hint about how to convert xml file into different tables by the xml attribute?
This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="weatherdata.xsl"?>
<weatherdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-1" location="Calgary">
<maxtemp>1.1°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-6.1°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-2" location="Calgary">
<maxtemp>-3.4°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-18.2°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>5cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-3" location="Calgary">
<maxtemp>-18.1°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-21.1°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>1.6cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Charlottetown">
<maxtemp>-3.5°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-15°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0.4cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Charlottetown">
<maxtemp>-1°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-13.2°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0.6cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Charlottetown">
<maxtemp>-11.8°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-16.1°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Ottawa">
<maxtemp>-3°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-8.1°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0.2cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Ottawa">
<maxtemp>-3.8°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-15.8°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
<stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Ottawa">
<maxtemp>-9.6°C</maxtemp>
<mintemp>-15.5°C</mintemp>
<totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
<totalsnow>18cm</totalsnow>
</stationdata>
</weatherdata>
```

This is my xls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/weatherdata">
<html>
 <head>
 <title>weather data</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<h1>Calgary-Temperature Summary(2015)</h1>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
        <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
    </tr>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </table>
 </body>
</html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="stationdata">
<tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are the location names - Calgary, Charlottetown and Ottawa - known in advance? IOW, can they be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the location names - Calgary, Charlottetown and Ottawa - are known in advance and always present, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
        <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/weatherdata">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>weather data</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Calgary-Temperature Summary(2015)</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Calgary']"/>
            </table>
            <h1>Charlottetown-Temperature Summary(2015)</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Charlottetown']"/>
            </table>
            <h1>Ottawa-Temperature Summary(2015)</h1>
            <table border="1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Ottawa']"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stationdata">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It filter data under the 3 different cities perfectly,  but all the data are not organized in the tables, I tried to add <table> tags, it doesn`t  work. @michael.hor257k

Comment: "*all the data are not organized in the tables*" I am not sure what you mean by that. The result is three tables, each with three rows of data. There are 9 `stationdata`  elements in  your XML - so what exactly is missing?

Comment: It works now, I just  replaced the output method="xml" in the prolog the output method="html" . @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 1):

This is a grouping question. Since you're using XSLT 1.0, you can use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

You can create an `xsl:key` based on the `location` attribute.

Then you loop over the first match of each key and output the location.

Then you apply-templates to all matches with that key.

**XML Input**

```
<weatherdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-1" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>1.1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-6.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-2" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>-3.4°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-18.2°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>5cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-3" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>-18.1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-21.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>1.6cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-3.5°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.4cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-13.2°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.6cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-11.8°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-16.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-3°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-8.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.2cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-3.8°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15.8°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-9.6°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15.5°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>18cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
</weatherdata>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="locations" match="stationdata" use="@location"/>

  <xsl:template match="/weatherdata">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>weather data</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="stationdata[count(.|key('locations',@location)[1])=1]">
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="@location"/>-Temperature Summary (<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@weatherdate,'-')"/>)</h1>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Data</th>
              <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
              <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
              <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
              <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('locations',@location)"/>
          </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stationdata">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   
      <title>weather data</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Calgary-Temperature Summary (2015)</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Maximum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Minimum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
            <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-1-1</td>
            <td>1.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>-6.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-1-2</td>
            <td>-3.4&deg;C</td>
            <td>-18.2&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>5cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-1-3</td>
            <td>-18.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>-21.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>1.6cm</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <h1>Charlottetown-Temperature Summary (2015)</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Maximum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Minimum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
            <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-01</td>
            <td>-3.5&deg;C</td>
            <td>-15&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0.4cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-02</td>
            <td>-1&deg;C</td>
            <td>-13.2&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0.6cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-03</td>
            <td>-11.8&deg;C</td>
            <td>-16.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0cm</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <h1>Ottawa-Temperature Summary (2015)</h1>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Maximum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Minimum Temperature(&deg;C)</th>
            <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
            <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-01</td>
            <td>-3&deg;C</td>
            <td>-8.1&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0.2cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-02</td>
            <td>-3.8&deg;C</td>
            <td>-15.8&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>0cm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2015-01-03</td>
            <td>-9.6&deg;C</td>
            <td>-15.5&deg;C</td>
            <td>0 mm</td>
            <td>18cm</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

XSLT 2.0 example mentioned in comments. As you can see, there's not much difference for this basic example. We just use `xsl:for-each-group` instead of a key.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/weatherdata">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>weather data</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="stationdata" group-by="@location">
          <h1><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>-Temperature Summary (<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@weatherdate,'-')"/>)</h1>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Data</th>
              <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
              <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
              <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
              <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </table>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stationdata">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work perfectly.  I am new to XSL,   is this would be much easier on XSL 2.0? @Daniel Haley

Comment: @Z.Zhe - For this small example, it's not much easier in 2.0. However, if your grouping gets more complicated or if there is other areas that need to be transformed further (like formatting dates, etc.) then it will be much easier in 2.0. I will update my answer with a 2.0 example. Also, if this answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking on the check mark (✅) next to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @ Daniel Haley, I will try to study the link you provide. really appreciate